# How to tweet via Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I am using the [Twitter](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter) gem for a company web app, called 'Foobar'. I also have a Twitter account called 'Foobar'. I am trying to tweet onto my Foobar Twitter account from the web app.

From the readme docs:

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = 'YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY'
  config.consumer_secret = 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET'
  config.oauth_token = 'YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN'
  config.oauth_token_secret = 'YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET'
end

client = Twitter::Client.new
client.update('Hello, from Twitter Gem!')
```

I have the consumer_key and consumer_secret. But how do I get the oauth token and oauth token secret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new application as a developer on twitter. You will get your token after you create it.
http://dev.twitter.com/apps/new

For more information:
http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq

Comment: I have created an application and it only gives me the consumer_key and consumer_secret, as described in my initial post

Comment: Checkout this auto flow graphic:
http://si0.twimg.com/images/dev/oauth_diagram.png

You first have to submit your consumer key and other data - and then twitter responds with the oauth token.

Comment: Read this:
http://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/twitter-oauth-and-ruby-on-rails-integrated-cookbook-style-in-the-console-updated-for-twitter-1-0/

Jump down to the third code block. You have to first submit your consumer token and token secret to twitter - then it spits back the request token and request token secret for you to use in your app config.

Comment: does this mean tweets will only work on production, and not development? Do the keys get utilized in development as well? the domain name for twitter is set to the site's url, so i'm guessing localhost stuff won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an application in https://dev.twitter.com

- You have to mention the application name,Description and website if you have any.
- You will get the consumer_key and consumer_secret.
- Make sure that you have changed the access level as required to your application.
- After that click the create access token button in the same page.
- It will create the access token and access token secret.
- You should use the access token as oath_token and access token secret as oath_token_secret..